# Are two graphs isomorphic in python, no imports

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, isomorphism

I am writing a function `is_iso(graph1, graph2)` that takes in two graphs as its input, and then determines whether or not the two graphs are isomorphic.

I can assume that the two graphs will have the same number of vertices and that the names used on the vertices will be the same.

`is_iso({“A” : [“B”, “C”], “B” : [“A”], “C” : [“A”]}, {“A” : [“B”], “B” : [“A”, “C”], “C” : [“B”]})` should return `True`

`is_iso({“A” : [“B”, “C”], “B” : [“A”, “C”], “C” : [“A”, “B”]}, {“A” : [“B”, “C”], “B” : [“A”], “C” :[“A”]})` should return `False`

```
def is_iso(graph1,graph2):
    for vertex in graph1:#loops through every vertex in graph1 
         seq1 += [len(graph1[vertex])]#adds the degree of each vertex to the list

    for vertex in graph2: #loops through every vertex in graph2 
        seq2 += [len(graph2[vertex])]#adds the degree of each vertex to the list

    return sorted(seq1) == sorted(seq2)
```

All my method currently checks if the degree sequence is the same but graphs can have the same degree sequence and not be isomorphic. I am not sure how to finish checking from here. I am not allowed to import any libraries. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Graph isomorphism is a hard problem (conjectured to be somewhere between P and NP-complete). Entire books have been written about it. It is unreasonable for you to expect a description of a graph-isomorphism algorithm on Stack Overflow (although some version of brute-force for smallish graphs is reasonable enough). What algorithm have you decided to use? If you don't know -- research it. If you get stuck at a specific point in your implementation, then ask a question.

Comment: It would also be unethical for us to provide the meat of the answer to your homework problem. We can help with debugging, but you've got to at the very least attempt a solution first.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me I'm asking for assistance with the logic. I've obviously already attempted the problem because I have part of it written.

Comment: The problem as stated uses the same names on the vertices, so it's easy and does not fit into the generalized isomorphism class of difficult problems.  Just sort and compare directly... which OP has realized and has tried to do.

Comment: Any isomorphism must send nodes of a given degree to nodes of a given degree. Find a way to 1) enumerate such degree-preserving mappings and 2) check if they are isomorphic. This will give you a brute-force algorithm which will be more than adequate for problems of this size.

Comment: @tom10 I don't read the problem that way -- there is no restriction which says that `"A"` can only map to `"A"`, so there are still `n!` potential isomorphisms.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Maybe I misunderstand then.. what else does it mean when the question states, "...names used on the vertices will be the same"

Comment: @tom10 Graphs on a given sets of nodes can be non-identical but nevertheless isomorphic. Look at OP's example of an input which should be true.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Yes, that's a valid definition. I think the problem is that there are two definitions of "isomorphism" for [labeled graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism).

Comment: @tom10 I see what you were thinking -- but look at the last paragraph of the section on isomorphisms of labeled graphs. In OP's case it would be trivial if isomorphisms are constrained to be label-preserving, so that is unlikely to be the intent here.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Yes, I think you are right.  My read (ie, the easier definition of labeled isomorphism) would make the first example false.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest possible implementation is just to brute-force it. We need to try all possible start points in one of the graphs:

```
for all start points v1 in G1
    try to find an isomorphism rooted at v1 in G1 to any of v2 in G2
```

but what does the second line mean?! Well, something like:

```
for each neighbour i in G1[v1]
    for each neighbour j in G2[v2]
        match(i, j)
```

note that we also have to keep track of the nodes we have matched so far and return true as soon as we find a match.

We can improve matters by using the degree sequence - obviously vertices of the same degree in each graph must match, so only consider these as candidates for a match.

There are, of course, much more elaborate algorithms out there, but that only really matters if you need speed or have large graphs. For reference, consider the VF2 algorithm:

[VF2 algorithm steps with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176298/vf2-algorithm-steps-with-example)

Comment: Could we see some working code for this please?

Comment: @RobinAndrews I could do ... but why? The original question is 4 years old, so hopefully the questioner has either implemented it by now or moved on. If anyone actually wants to check two graphs for isomorphism they should use nAUTy/traces or Weisfeiler-Lehman or, like I say, VF2. Or just implement the VF2 algorithm, it's not that hard.

Comment: I would be to help me to understand the problem from first principles. I find writing code (including someone else's) to be the best way to understand algorithmic and mathematical concepts. Using libraries or sophisticated implementations doesn't help in the same way.